# Irreducibles in ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, quotient-group

Let $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ be the ring of polynomials in 2 variables over the complex numbers and let $(xy)$ be the ideal generated by $xy$. Find all prime ideals of $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x, y]}{(xy)}$.

Attempted solution:

By nature of prime ideals, $0 \in P$ for every prime ideal $P$. Furthermore, in the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x, y]}{(xy)}$ we have that $xy = 0$. Therefore $xy \in P$ for every prime ideal in the quotient. By definition of prime ideals, this implies either $x$ or $y \in P$ for every prime ideal. Now, prime ideals in the quotient ring take the form $(p,f(x))$ where $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Therefore, all prime ideals in the quotient will take the form $(p,x), (p,y), (p,x,y)$ where $p = 0$ or a prime in $\mathbb{C}$.

Is this formalism correct / effectively address the question?

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{C}[x.y]/(xy)$ are not polynomials, they are cosets of $(xy)$. $x$ is not an element of the ring you are looking at, so how could $x\in P$ hold? You can say that $x+(xy)$ or $y+(xy)$ lie in every prime ideal, but not $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Prime ideals of $\mathbb C[xy]/(xy)$ are in bijection with prime ideals of $\mathbb C$ containing $xy$. But if $xy\in\mathfrak p$ then $x\in\mathfrak p$ or $y\in\mathfrak p$. The prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset\mathbb C[x,y]$ with $x\in\mathfrak p$ are further in bijection with prime ideals of $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x)\cong\mathbb C[y]$, which are well-known (it is a PID.) Similarly, one may classify all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ containing $y$.

Comment: @KentaS I am a bit confused as to how my solution fails to capture this -- could you expand a bit?

Comment: "where $p=0$ or a prime in $\mathbb C$"--what does this mean? $\mathbb C$ does not have any prime ideals.